# Disable inaccessible links in Dokuwiki?

Tags: hyperlink, dokuwiki

Is there any way in Dokuwiki to make links to inaccessible articles (due to insufficient access rights) appear disabled?

I would prefer such a link to be gray and inactive, with perhaps a lock icon, rather than having the user getting an error message when the link is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would basically require to disable the cache for each and every page and make your wiki much slower. So I guess the answer is no.

Comment: OK, thanks. It's a pity though from a usability perspective. Still the most practical wiki I've tried.

Comment: If you can live with _regularly_ disabled cache though, a partial solution would be to modify the code of the `internal_link` function to check ACL before. The links will still function normally but would be rendered as they were the _last_ time the DW cache was generated. Only useful if you have something like a cronjob to regularly clear your cache though.

Comment: @Luis Machuca: Thanks, maybe I'll give it a shot. It's a good idea for a new DokuWiki extension I think.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, something like

```
global $ID;
if ( auth_quickaclcheck ( $id ) < AUTH_READ ){
  ...here add .acldisable to $id;
  ...here add class "disabled" to $id;
}
```

in core link renderer

and in CSS add `.acldisable { color: gray; }`